# Which headers are ALWAYS returned in a reply/forward?

Tags: email, smtp

I'm making a webstore with integrated customer service. Every few minutes, the system will retrieve emails into the database, parsing headers and relating the message to customers and orders.

Customer threading is fairly reliable via the messages `From:` header. But what about orders? It seems most people use the `Reply-To:` header for threading orders ...

```
From: <orders@company.com>
To: <person@place.com>
Subject: Company Order #314159
Reply-To: <order-314159@company.com>
```

But a messy `Reply-to:` obscures and uglifies things, and probably flags spam sensors or something. I definitely don't want to count on the `Subject:` field, people modify the subject all the time, even when replying. There are other headers that seem suited to the job, like ...

```
From: <orders@company.com>
To: <person@place.com>
Subject: Company Order #314159
Message-ID: <314159-2>
```

... or ...

```
In-Reply-To: <314159-1>
```

But are these sent back when the person reply? Are there any headers (other than `Reply-To:`) that are reliably copied into replies and forwards?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't rely entirely on headers being preserved. When replying or forwarding, a mail client creates a new message; that mail client can quite legitimately ignore or alter any content, as deemed appropriate.

You might be able to track by the following means, but all are vulnerable to alteration (mainly by the user, but also by a primitive mail client). You should really just use them to make a best-guess.

1. A [disposable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disposable_email_address) Reply-To address. Theoretically, you can also do it with "From" if you want, but Reply-To is better to ensure the user (and their mail server/client) recognise it's from you and act appropriately. I see no reason why a spam filter would care about disposable addresses. Seeing as most spam uses fake addresses anyway and doesn't care about replies, it is not really a spammer trick. It's unlikely to cause a substantial increase in spam filtering. Using a Reply-To for the same domain as your From address is also unlikely to look suspicious.
2. A unique subject. Yes, it can easily be changed, but usually the existing subject is appended to, rather than deleted (especially if it obviously contains some kind of reference number). You could apply a regular expression match - maybe only using it as a confirmation of your other detection methods.
3. A unique string in the body (possibly preceded by the words "DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE")
4. The `In-Reply-To` and `Reference` headers are probably fine, when supported. There is a small chance that a user will copy their reply into a new blank message and trash the headers anyway.

Answer (score 2):

`Reply-To` is sadly not entirely reliable. All replies should have `References:` which is better standardized than `In-Reply-To:` which is not easily machine readable.

Your best bet may be to set the envelope header to a unique identifier, perhaps with a `From:` and `Sender:` combo that directs replies to the right place but displays nicely.

See also tangentially Dan Bernstein's notes; http://cr.yp.to/immhf.html and in particular http://cr.yp.to/immhf/thread.html

I don't think you can count on *anything* when it comes to forwards.

Comment: @StevenPenny Care to explain your edit? I think it's worth noting that Microsoft's clients are particularly pesky when it comes to breaking interoperability (including, but not limited to, ignoring `Reply-To`).

Comment: As a Windows user, I agree the system is crippled in many ways. However it would be better served to source your grievances than to just hurl insults

Answer (score 0):

Although you have already received some answers, however, we had a similar situation where we supposed to send emails to customers and read them back and associated them with various activities.

During the research the the only HEADER we found that does not get replaced or Removed by the various email clients (Outook, Yahoo, Gmail etc.) was "XREF". 
We have thoroughly tested it and it has been working since we first introduced it.

Comment: Xref is only used with netnews protocol, while References and in-reply-to are used in mail protocol, my source is this https://www.iana.org/assignments/message-headers/message-headers.xhtml

Comment: Thanks you for your input; will have a look at the resource that you shared.

Comment: Bringing to topic back from the dead:
has anyone figured out which header (or reference) can survive reply by Gmail and MS-Outlook
If yes, any thoughts about future-proofing this?