# PHP imap check automated reply

Tags: php, imap

I have been looking around and found no solution for this issue.

Let say our server sends an email out to a user that has a "out of office" , "on vacation" , "to busy" etc.

This message will be sent back to our server and parsed once again, sending out another email, hence creating a big loop.

Other than directly checking for "out of office", "on vacation" "to busy" messages is there another way using the IMAP PHP commands ?

Thank you fro any responses!

Comment: Check for loops in the parser.

Comment: Why is your server sending automatic responses? Is it a support ticketing system, or something else?

Comment: Set a non-existing 'do-not-reply@example.com' Reply-To: address on the outgoing message, so even if the client does send an autoresponse, it'll just get dropped on the floor?

Comment: Yes its a helpdesk, good idea on the reply to address. That will work perfect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't bothered about handling replies, then as Marc B suggests, you can change your reply-to address.

However, it is quite a common feature for helpdesk systems to handle replies and then link them to the existing ticket. In the case of an autoresponse and a support ticket, it will let your support staff know that a) the customer has received your message; b) any special information or instructions from the customer's autoresponder.

For general messages, it allows your customers the basic convenience of being able to contact you via a reply.

It takes more effort, but if you have the flexibility to achieve it, you can apply one or more of the options discussed in [Which headers are ALWAYS returned in a reply/forward?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323116/which-headers-are-always-returned-in-a-reply-forward/9335397#9335397) - in this case, it would be particularly useful to have a disposable email address, which links the autoresponse to the appropriate helpdesk ticket.

Comment: Obviously, the assumption I've made is that you will not send a confirmation response to replies for an existing ticket, which is how most helpdesk systems behave.

Comment: I forgot to give you credit for your answer, what I found was our send_mail program was sending a line that was the same in every email so i was able to parse it better!